# How to make inner div full height with unknown height parent?

Tags: html, css

I need `.col` to be 100% of `.row` height but you can see that the second `.col` falls short. How can I get this to work without using any *"magic numbers"*?

http://jsfiddle.net/b21g6fme/

```css
.row {
    position: relative;
    background: #f99;
}
.col {
    margin: 0 0 0 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #999;
    height: 100%;
}
.col:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
.item {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin: 12px 0 0 0;
    min-height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: 4px solid black;
}
.item:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
.item.large {
    min-height: 120px;
    height: 100%;
}
.item.red {
    background: #f00;
}
.item.blue {
    background: #0f0;
}
.item.green {
    background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="item red"></div>
        <div class="item blue"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="large item green"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell us or draw what kind of result you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `flexbox`:

- Add `display: flex;` to `.row`. This tells its children to use the `flexbox` model
- Add `flex-direction: row;` to `.row` as we want the children to align horizontally
- Add `display: flex;` to `.col`. This tells its children to use the `flexbox` model
- Add `flex-direction: column;` to `.col` as we want the children to align vertically
- Add `flex: 1;` to `.item` to allow it to grow and fill the available space if required
- A number of styles can be removed from your original version as they are no longer required when using `flexbox`

```css
.row {
    background:#f99;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.col {
    background: #999;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin:0 0 0 12px;
    width:40%;
}
.col:first-child {
    margin:0;
}
.item {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 12px 0 0 0;
    min-height: 80px;
    outline:4px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}
.item:first-child {
    margin:0;
}
.item.red {
    background:#f00;
}
.item.blue {
    background:#0f0;
}
.item.green {
    background:#00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="item red"></div>
        <div class="item blue"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="large item green"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`flexbox` support is pretty good, although it isn't supported by older versions of IE. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via flexbox if you don't care about any IE below 11.

I showed how it can be done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/opportunato/9ahow7qk/).

```
.row {
    position: relative;
    background:#f99;
    display: flex;
}

.col {
    margin:0 0 0 8px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:40%;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align:top;
    background: #999;
}
.col:first-child {
    margin:0;
}
.col:last-child {
    display:flex;
}

.item {
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    margin: 12px 0 0 0;
    min-height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    outline:4px solid black;
}
.item:first-child {
    margin:0;
}

.item.large {
    min-height:120px;
}

.item.red {
    background:#f00;
}
.item.blue {
    background:#0f0;
}
.item.green {
    background:#00f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplified CSS table layout, the trick is set the full height div to absolute position with top and bottom both set to 0.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0qug9hhy/)**

```css
.row {
    display: table;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
.item.large {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.item.red {
    background: red;
}
.item.blue {
    background: blue;
}
.item.green {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="item red">r<br/>e<br/>d</div>
        <div class="item blue">blue</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="large item green">green</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Children item height in percentage value will only work if parent item have height defined.

Otherwise you can achieve it with jQuery

```
$(".col").height($(".row").height());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
.large.item {
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make the parent relative positioned, and the child absolute possitioned, giving the child a value of 0 for top an bottom will make it stretch to the parents full height.

Comment: Care for a snippet or a Fiddle?